# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .ui.activities.MainActivity on devices lower API Level 19

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I'm getting this strange error on the pre KitKat devices:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{me.bitfrom.whattowatch/me.bitfrom.whattowatch.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.bitfrom.whattowatch.ui.activities.MainActivity
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.bitfrom.whattowatch.ui.activities.MainActivity
                                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On devices with API Level >= 19 everything OK. I thought that it could be dex limit, but [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) approach didn't help.

UPD: My MainActivity implements `Transition.TransitionListener`, but I'm using `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My MainActivity implements Transition.TransitionListener

That's probably your problem. That interface only exists on API Level 19 and higher. Older devices do not have that interface, and therefore cannot load your class.

> but I'm using @SuppressLint("NewApi") annotation

All that does is prevent your IDE from complaining. It does not cause older devices to get `Transition` or `Transition.TransitionListener`.

Rather than implementing it on the activity, implement that interface on something else that you only use on API Level 19+ devices, such as an anonymous inner class instance.

Comment: I thought that @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) above every overrided method will help( Thank you.